# Cannot set monitor mode on my TL-WN772Nv2, Cannot allocate memory error

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

I've rencently bought the TL-WN772N (v2) and I'm trying to set it up for monitor mode, I managed to install the drivers (the adapter is able to connect to the network) and change modes (into auto / managed), however whenever I try to change the mode into monitor I get hit with:
[image],
and I do not undersand why, it's not like it's lacking memory (first time seeing this problem, so have mercy please :D)

I'm running kali (6.1.0-kali7-amd64)